# Arithmetic operation between Meteor Helpers

Tags: mongodb, math, meteor, helper

I am handling a new Meteor test project and came across a doubt.. Please try to find a solution for me.

This application has 2 'helpers' for the same template.

```
     Template.scoreBoard.helpers({

        scroeHalfTime:function(){
               var cursor = return MyCollection.find({player:"selectedPlayer"}).fetch();
               var sum = 0;
               cursor.forEach(function(player){
               sum = sum + Number(player.scoreHalf)});
               return sum;
        },
        scroeFullTime:function(){
               var cursor = return MyCollection.find({player:"selectedPlayer"}).fetch();
               var sum = 0;
               cursor.forEach(function(player){
               sum = sum + Number(player.scoreFull)});
               return sum;
}
```

I would like to return the difference between this 'scroeHalfTime' and 'scroeFullTime', this will give me a result of how much did the player scored before and after half time.

Following codes did not work for me..

```
{{ScroeFullTime - scroeHalfTime}}
{{ScroeFullTime() - scroeHalfTime()}}
{{(ScroeFullTime - scroeHalfTime)}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved..

Created Another Helper, and now Template. scoreBoard.helpers looks like,

```
Template.scoreBoard.helpers({

        scroeHalfTime:function(){
               var cursor = return MyCollection.find({player:"selectedPlayer"}).fetch();
               var sum = 0;
               cursor.forEach(function(player){
               sum = sum + Number(player.scoreHalf);
        });
               return sum;
        },
        scroeFullTime:function(){
               var cursor = return MyCollection.find({player:"selectedPlayer"}).fetch();
               var sum = 0;
               cursor.forEach(function(player){
               sum = sum + Number(player.scoreFull)});
               return sum;
        },


        scoreDifference:function(fullTime,halfTime){
        var halfCursor = return MyCollection.find({player:"selectedPlayer"}).fetch();
        var halfScore = 0;
        halfCursor.forEach(function(player){
        halfScore = halfScore + Number(player.scoreHalf);
        })


        var fullCursor = return MyCollection.find({player:"selectedPlayer"}).fetch();
        var fullScore = 0;
        fullCursor.forEach(function(player){
        fullScore = fullScore + Number(player.scoreFull);
        })
        });

        return fullScore - halfScore;

}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create variable which will hold both values, like

```
var halfTime=0, fullTime=0;

Template.scoreBoard.helpers({

        scroeHalfTime:function(){
               var cursor = return MyCollection.find({player:"selectedPlayer"}).fetch();
               var sum = 0;
               cursor.forEach(function(player){
               sum = sum + Number(player.scoreHalf)});
               halfTime = sum;
               return sum;
        },
        scroeFullTime:function(){
               var cursor = return MyCollection.find({player:"selectedPlayer"}).fetch();
               var sum = 0;
               cursor.forEach(function(player){
               sum = sum + Number(player.scoreFull)});
               fullTime = sum;
               return sum;
         },
         difference: function(){
              return fullTime - halfTime;
         }
```

Comment: Variable Declared inside One Helper doesn't work in another.. That's why I wrote the long code..

Comment: And as you can see in my example variables are declared outside of helpers

Comment: @Sindis, your solution works as long as one use the helpers in a specific order. IMHO, it's better to no cache the `halfTime` and `fullTime` values, but to re calculate them in the `difference` helper, in order to avoid bugs. Further more, the `fullTime` helper won't be reactive.

Comment: I avoid rewriting code if there is a way to do it once, if you use both helpers in same place they will calcualte simultaneously so there is no need to write another, and since helpers are reactive, fullTime will be aswell

Answer (score 0):

Simple call `{{scoreFullTime - scoreHalf Time}}`. You can do that inside the template.

Comment: From inside your template you can just do `{{function() - function()}}`. That should be all you need.

Comment: Oops, sorry! Should be without `()`.

Comment: Did you try surrounding the whole expression with parens? Something like `{{(scoreFullTime - scoreHalfTime)}}`?

Comment: I don't think one can use `-` as the difference operator in Spacebars. Or have they added it recently?